# html2canvas screenshot size controle

Tags: html2canvas

I use this code from taking a screenshot & save it to pdf, I want to control the screenshot size like 400x700px.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function genPDF() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("all_content"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG',20,20);
            doc.save("Businesscard-<?php echo $sss_name; ?>.pdf");
        }
    });
}


  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **height** and **width** attribute to get you desired *outcome* :

```
function genPDF() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("all_content"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            canvas.setAttribute('width',400);       /*this->add*/
            canvas.setAttribute('height',700);      /*this->add*/
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG');
            doc.save("Businesscard-<?php echo $sss_name; ?>.pdf");
        }
    });
}
```